# jquery execute click event only if it has finished previous execution

Tags: jquery

i want click event to execute only if it has finished previous execution. My code is

```
$(".next").click(function(){

$(this).parent().find('.overlay').css({'display':'block'});
addContent(options, speed, 1);


});
```

Comment: What is the previous execution ?

Comment: does addContent function performs some asynchronous task?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is to just [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) the click event handler when you start the task and bind it again when the task is done.

Comment: it's better use `on/off` instead of `bind/unbind`

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan If you have jQuery 1/7+, yes, it's recommended to prefer [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) over `unbind`.

Comment: my addContent() function consist too much code, that addContent() is not fully executed and click event is binded what should i do.

Comment: call unbind (or off) at the start of addContent, and call the click function again to rebind it at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some sort of callback or deferred object to know when your addContent function has completed, and then do something like:

```
$(".next").on('click', doStuff);

function doStuff() {
    $(".next").off('click', doStuff);
    $(this).parent().find('.overlay').css('display', 'block');
    addContent(options, speed, 1, function() {  //<-- callback
        $(".next").on('click', doStuff);
    });
}

function addContent(options, speed, num, callback) {
    options.animate({left: num}, speed, function() {
        callback();  //<-- call callback when function is completed
    });
}
```